# deriving Applicative in haskell

Tags: haskell

Why wouldn't GHC derive `Applicative` for `KO` ?

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-17.10 script

{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype KO a = KO a deriving (Functor, Applicative) -- doesn't derive Applicative

newtype OK f a = OK (f a) deriving (Functor, Applicative) -- that's ok

main :: IO ()
main = print "hello"
```

> • Can't make a derived instance of ‘Applicative KO’
> (even with cunning GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving):
> cannot eta-reduce the representation type enough
> • In the newtype declaration for ‘KO’typecheck

Comment: if you `:i Applicative` you'll see this: `type Applicative :: (* -> *) -> Constraint` - so a type can be applicative if it's kind is `* -> *` (the *container* is applicative - like `[]` or `Maybe` - not `[a]`, `Maybe a`) - that's why it is not working - your newtype is a wrapper for *any* type - if you'd make an instance for `OK` you would do `Applicative f => instance Applicative (OK f)` (`Ok f : * -> *`) - try to write an instance for `KO` yourself - there is one (basically `Identity` - look it up) - but it's not what you would expect from a newtype *wrapper*

Comment: If the `Identity` behaviour is what you want, you could use `DerivingVia` and say `newtype KO a = KO a deriving (Functor, Applicative) via Identity`

Comment: `deriving via` is more regular and less surprise

Comment: @Carsten you are right I imagine. the difference of treatment re `Functor` vs `Applicative` is a bit surprising. I wonder what the downside would be to align both on Functor.

Comment: @Carsten, fwiw, `:i Functor` also shows `type Functor :: (* -> *) -> Constraint`. Why doesn't `Functor` pose the same problem, then?

Comment: @Enlico `Functor` doesn't pose the same problem because it is using a different instance generation method. My answer has some details and a link to the full documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHC has four ways of creating instances:

- `stock`: write new implementations of each of the class's methods from scratch via pattern matching and the like
- `newtype`: when declaring a `newtype` that wraps a type that already has an instance, reuse that instance, inserting and removing newtype wrappers at the appropriate moments
- `anyclass`: declare an instance with no method definitions (hence using default implementations for every method, if there are any)
- `via`: a generalization of `newtype`, it lets you inherit the instance from any other type with visibly the same representation, again by inserting/removing newtype wrappers at appropriate moments

In your code snippet, the `stock` method is used to derive `Functor` because you have turned on `DeriveFunctor`. There is currently no `stock` derivation for `Applicative`, though. The `via` method only ever fires when explicitly requested, and you have not turned on `DeriveAnyClass`, so the only option left is `newtype`, so GHC attempts to inherit an instance from the wrapped type. Then it runs into trouble, because `Applicative` is supposed to be for container types, and the contained type isn't one, so it complains.

This explains the `Functor` vs `Applicative` difference for your first snippet. For the first vs second snippet difference for `Applicative`, we need only observe that after unwrapping the second one, we *do* have a container type; hence you get an `Applicative` instance for `OK` any time its `f` argument has one.

See also the documentation on [deriving strategies](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/deriving_strategies.html).

Comment: I think `deriving (Functor)` changes strategy depending on the kind of `newtype` involved (which make sense). I will post some example

Comment: @nicolas The documentation I linked describes the algorithm GHC uses to decide which strategy to use.

Comment: @DanielWagner `via` is not merely the dual of `newtype`. it subsumes `newtype`, and in essence, the requirement is just that the original type and the via-type are representationally equivalent. Whether the via-type is wrapped in more or fewer newtype wrappers than the original type is secondary ...

Comment: it describes it "if possible" ;)  "stock: Have GHC implement a “standard” instance for a data type, **if possible**"

Comment: @nicolas The next section is the algorithm I was referring to, and says when it is possible: "those specified in the report and those enabled by language extensions", with "language extensions" being a link to... well, it's probably intended to link [here](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/deriving_extra.html), which lists the extensions and which classes they enable.

Comment: @kosmikus Thanks! I've corrected my description.

Comment: @DanielWagner it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the answer, here's some more detailed sample highlighting the two behaviors.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- deriving Functor
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

newtype F a = F {unF :: a} deriving (Functor)

-- translates to

newtype F' a = F' a

deriving instance Functor F' -- F' endowed with instance -- (stock strategy)

-- whereas

newtype HF f a = HF {unHF :: f a} deriving (Functor)

-- delegates to
newtype HF' f a = HF' (f a)

deriving instance Functor f => Functor (HF' f) -- HF' f delegates to f

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- deriving Applicative
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

-- -- commented for typecheck
-- newtype G a = G a deriving (Functor, Applicative)

-- -- translates to pb
-- newtype G' a = G' a

-- deriving instance Functor G'

-- deriving instance Applicative G' -- G' not endowed with instance

-- -- whereas

newtype HG f a = HG (f a) deriving (Functor)

-- delegates

newtype HG' f a = HG' (f a)

deriving instance Functor f => Functor (HG' f) -- delegates to f

deriving instance Applicative f => Applicative (HG' f) -- delegates to f

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

---

-- Endows with a Functor instance
-- >>>  unF $ (+ 1) <$> F 6
-- 7

-- Delegates the functor instance to f
-- >>> unHF $ (+1) <$> HF (Just 6)
-- Just 7

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Comment: I find this snippet fairly misleading. In all of the `Functor` cases shown here, your "delegates to" happens via stock deriving, not via generalized newtype deriving, which seems to be what you are implying.

Comment: I just meant to highlight the difference, not how such differences arise in the implementation

Comment: What difference are you highlighting that was not in the original question?

Comment: it's a more symmetrical presentation of *the* two behaviors. I don't imply anything, or at least I try not too (hence the more detailed code here..)

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate how `DerivingVia` is more explicit about each choice, here's a translation of each choice

```hs
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-17.10 script

{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- Legacy
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

-- Endows with a Functor instance
newtype FStock a = FStock {unFStock :: a} deriving (Functor)

-- >>>  unFStock $ (+ 1) <$> FStock 6
-- 7

-- Delegates the functor instance to f
newtype HFDel f a = HFDel {unHFDel :: f a} deriving (Functor)

-- >>> unHFDel $ (+1) <$> HFDel (Just 6)
-- Just 7

-- bad = unHFDel $ (+ 1) <$> HFDel 6 -- error nothing to delegate to

deriving instance Applicative f => Applicative (HFDel f)

-- >>> unHFDel $ (HFDel (Just (+1))) <*> HFDel (Just 6)
-- Just 7

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- Deriving Via
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

newtype F a = F {unF :: a}

deriving via Identity instance Functor F

deriving via Identity instance Applicative F

-- Endows with instances, by explicitely delegating to the Identity
-- >>> unF $ (+ 1) <$> F 6
-- 7
-- >>> unF $ F (+ 1) <*> F 6
-- 7

newtype G f a = G {unG :: f a}

-- Delegates explicitely the instances to f
deriving via (f :: * -> *) instance (Functor f) => Functor (G f)

deriving via (f :: * -> *) instance (Applicative f) => Applicative (G f)

-- >>> unG $ (+1) <$> G (Just 6)
-- Just 7

-- bad = unG $ (+1) <$> G 6 -- error nothing to delegate to

-- >>> unG $ G (Just (+1)) <*> G (Just 6)
-- Just 7

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- legacy
  print $ unFStock $ (+ 1) <$> FStock 6 -- 7
  print $ unHFDel $ (+ 1) <$> HFDel (Just 6) -- Just 7
  --print $ unHFDel $ (+ 1) <$> HFDel 6 -- error nothing to delegate to
  print $ unHFDel $ (HFDel (Just (+ 1))) <*> HFDel (Just 6) -- Just 7
  -- deriving via
  print $ unF $ (+ 1) <$> F 6 -- 7
  print $ unF $ F (+ 1) <*> F 6 -- 7
  print $ unG $ (+ 1) <$> G (Just 6) -- Just 7
  -- print $ unG $ (+ 1) <$> G 6 -- error nothing to delegate to
  print $ unG $ G (Just (+ 1)) <*> G (Just 6) -- Just 7
```